# Terraform mkdir no such file or directory

Tags: terraform

Learning Terraform and running into a weird issue when trying to create a directory. When this resource is executed it returns:

> Error running command 'mkdir /home/user-a/docker': no such file or
> directory.

This command works locally on the target just fine. This is building a directory to put docker data.

```
resource "null_resource" "dockerarm1"{
    connection {
        type     = "ssh"
        user     = "user-a"
        password = "sojfadsfsdfsa"
        host     = "dockerarm1.local"
      }
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "mkdir /home/user-a/docker"
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried mkdir -p ?

Comment: Try `mkdir -p /home/user-a/docker`

Comment: yes, it said operation not supported

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Marcin the OS on the remote machine is Ubuntu 20.04. I am executed TF on MacOS.

Comment: `local-exec` works on your mac. You need [remote-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec.html). Did you try that?

Comment: @Marcin omg I just spent so much time trying to get `local-exec` to work and I miss understood the document.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

`local-exec` executes on a local machine. To run your commands on a remote host (Ubuntu) you need to use [remote-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec.html):

> The remote-exec provisioner **invokes a script on a remote resource** after it is created.